# PHP - getting HTML articles from file or database?

Tags: php, html, database, file

There are several questions here about file vs. database, but I'm still not sure what to use and why I should use it in my case.

I have a site with quite a lot of HTML articles (between a couple of hundreds and a few thousand words long). In the database (MySQL) I have a version without the markup for the search index, and my question is what to do with the markup version – keep it in the database as well or in separate HTML files on the server (everything else being equal)?

Are there any obvious pros or cons with either approach or is it just a matter of taste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it is a matter of taste. If you are using a MYSQL database anyway, then I would strongly recommend keeping the markup version in the database as well, for those arguments:

- You would only need one system (the database) instead of two (database and filesystem), which would be much more consistent. It would require some programming work to sustain the consistency of filesystem and database.
- You could provide HTML the pages for download or direct view independently from the file system, and you can influence the URL as you like, e.g. insert date and title.
- Assumed your markup is XHTML valid, you could use MYSQL's XML path search functions, to search for specific contents (keywords, article headers, etc). Alternatively, you could use regular expressions for such operations. Thus, the database approach gives you, basically, more power over your material.

Nevertheless, here are some pros for the database/filesystem solution:

- The performance could be slightly better (depends on your load).
- If your database is disconnected for any reason, the articles will still be delivered by the webserver.
- In the short term (!), it could be less programming work.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm considering your arguments and getting somewhat more convinced by the hour ... :)